# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError itextpdf

Tags: java, hibernate, pdf, itext, websphere

I have a Spring hibernate application that uses itext 2.1.7 version for jasper reports and now i want to export pdf so i downloaded itext new jar 5.1.4.

However, when I deploy this application WAR to Websphere 7, the app doesn't run returning NoClassDefFoundError PdfPageEventHelper.

so the question is why can't i use the two versions (jars) as both of them don't have the same path first one is com.lowagie and the second jar is com.itextpdf.

I'd be very glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you add the full exception and stack trace?  The stack is useful to see the full message text (NoClassDefFoundError sometimes indicates an initialization failure, rather than a failure to find a class), and if there is a nested ClassNotFoundException, the stack will usually indicate what class loaders were used for the failed load.

Comment: And you are aware that iText v > 2 requires a commercial licence for non open source projects?

Comment: yes of course i know thanks a lot for your advice